# Scale bar when plotting a point cloud with lidR

Tags: r, rgl, lidar, lidr

How do I get a scalebar within my plot when plotting a point cloud from a `.las` file. I have a simple script below to plot my data using the `lidR` package but I want to add a scale bar and can't find how to do so.

```
las <- readLAS("<file.las>")
plot(las)
```

Comment: plot(las, legend = TRUE),  or plot(las, axis = TRUE, legend = TRUE).